# Syntax error in READ in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77

Im changing a code written in fortran 77 to Fortran 90. And when Im compiling  the follow error appears, I already search and I know that xint is declared as an array, so that is not the problem.

```
Integer :: n,nitp,m
Integer,parameter :: mdi1=3500
Double Precision :: xint(mdi1),yint(mdi1)

D500: do m=1,nitp
   read(4,*) n,xint(m),yint(m)
End Do D500

read(4,*) n,xint(m),yint(m)
              1
Error: Syntax error in READ statement at (1)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I try to explain better my problem Vladimir hopefully this would be enough, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Welcome. Please show use more code, this is not enough. We need to know what `n` is, what `xint` is and what `yint` is. How they are declared and where do their values come from. Saying it is an array is *not* enough, we need the code which should give us the same error you show. Please see [ask] and especially [mcve] to see what kind of code we need. It should be complete enough. One line is almost never enough. And don't forget to take the [tour].

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I tried to improve my question. If there is something else that you need to have a better idea of my problem dont hesitate to ask for it. Thanks again.

Comment: Please try the piece of code you provided whether it causes the error. I think it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as is, while what you are showing is not complete, compiles without problem on an old g95 compiler. I just copied it and compiled.

So I would say that unless you have an error in another part of the code (and in this case, please, show a more complete version) that is showing itself at this point, you probably have a format problem.

Check to see if you are using fixed format or if there are any "hidden" characters that your editor is putting in the file and that your compiler does not understand, like TABs or other characters.

Comment: You were right, I started over checking for every variable and now this error does not show anymore. I was having a problem with another variables. Anyway, thanks for the feedback. Greetings!